# Consulta php, Datos solo muestra ID_ clave foranea

Tags: php, mysql

buenas, me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para visualizar la columna "nombreModelo" dentro de mi consulta PHP, actualmente solo me muestra el ID de la clave foránea.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
       <?php
    $buscar = $_POST["patente"];
    $consulta= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM maquinas WHERE patente like '%$buscar%'");
   while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) 
   {
       ?> 
       <tr>
            <td class="estilo-tabla" align="left"> <a href="detallemaq.php" ><?=$registro['patente']?></a></td>
           <td class="estilo-tabla" align="left"><?=$registro['codigo_interno']?></td>
           <td class="estilo-tabla" align="left"><?=$registro['ano_maquina']?></td>
           <td class="estilo-tabla" align="left"><?=$registro['chasis_maquina']?></td>
           <td class="estilo-tabla" align="left"><?=$registro['vinserie_maquina']?></td>
           <td class="estilo-tabla" align="left"><?=$registro['motor_maquina']?></td>
           <td class="estilo-tabla" align="left"><?=$registro['id_modelofk']?></td>
       </tr> 
       <?php 
   } //fin blucle
?>
</table>
<?php
```

[image: Tabla "maquinas"]

[image: Tabla "modelosMaquina"]

Comment: En la consulta haz JOIN con la otra tabla usando id_modelo.

Comment: Tienes que hacer un inner join Seria algo asi como.  SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que tu otra tabla se llama **modelos**

`$consulta= mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM maquinas,modelos  WHERE maquinas.id_modelofk = modelos.id_modelo AND  maquinas.patente like '%$buscar%'");`

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! solucionado